# Google Sheets' COUNTIF doesn't function with boolean values

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, boolean, google-sheets-formula, countif

I'm looking for the equivalent of the `COUNTIF(A1:A100;TRUE)` formula of excel,
which won't happen to function in google sheets.
Had already tried to `SUM(--(A1:A100))`, neither this doesn't seem to do the job.

The above-mentioned formulas do function in excel/numbers, but in google sheets.
Google sheets outcome is zero for this formula.

Edit: Created a copy of the sheet and published -> [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vB7daidmTceqk1wsZomX9EK52akj9tppOzgMG8W2WdI/edit?usp=sharing)

Edit2: Was my fault... I used the german expression SUMIF() instead of COUNTIF(). Sheets should definitely not have multilingual expressions -.-
Credits goes to @AnonymesEinhorn. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the values in Google Sheets is the Boolean `TRUE` and not text?

Comment: Try `=COUNTIF(A1:A100,"True")`

Comment: Yes the values are booleans, since these are generated values with a formula. Even checked to multiply one of the values with =A1*1 and the result is 1, so they have to be booleans.

Neither =COUNTIF(A1:A100; "True") does the trick...

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: Tried even in various spelling such as "True","TRUE","true", "Wahr", "WAHR","wahr" ("Wahr" is the German expression for true).

Comment: what shows up when you do `=1=1` in a cell?

Comment: @player0 Created a copy and published it with edting rights. I have to count the Boolean values in E2:E80.

Comment: `=countif(E:E;true)` works on the test sheet you provided.

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah mixing up the terms in german sometimes. Thank you for editing.

Answer (score 1):

not sure how you getting those booleans but it works with text and even checkbox:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100; TRUE)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Why are you allowed to enter the expression TRUE like so?
The expression TRUE expects parantheses when I try to use it.

Comment: Well, it was my fault that sheets had expected parantheses. However the COUNTIF(E2:E80;TRUE) formula doesn't counts.

Comment: be aware that that there is boolean TRUE and formula =TRUE() - https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093307?hl=en&authuser=0

Comment: @SercanSametSavran did you try `=COUNTIF(E:E;TRUE())`

Comment: in E81 you had `SUMIF(E2:E80; TRUE)` not `COUNTIF(E2:E80;TRUE)`

Comment: @player0 yeah this was stupid... I've had started with the english expressions to work with excel back then and had to use german expressions for the last two years. Still mixing up the equivalent terms sometimes. :|